# How to Determine if the Packet List Pane in Wireshark is Displaying all the conversations between hosts?

Tags: wireshark

I am currently working with Wireshark for a project and the question I am asked to answer is: Does the Packet List Pane display all the conversation between the two hosts? Why? I am using a uploaded p.cap file and am using the filter: `(ip.src == 10.0.0.221) && (ip.dst == 122.167.99.148)` as shown. Based on what I am seeing in Wireshark, I do not think this filter is showing the full conversation but I am not sure why this is. Any assistance on this would be much appreciated. I have attached the image links below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2VX5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYLLk.png)

Comment: *Based on what I am seeing in Wireshark, I do not think this filter is showing the full conversation ...*  

Well, what are you seeing that makes you think that you're not seeing the full conversation?  You've apparently made some observation that has led you to this conclusion, so what observation have you made?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you are indeed not seeing the whole conversation, since your filter looks for just one side of the conversation (packets sent from 10.0.0.221 to 122.167.99.148). You can fix this easily by just changing `ip.src` and `ip.dst` to simply `ip`:

> (ip.src == 10.0.0.221) && (ip.dst == 122.167.99.148)

becomes

> (ip == 10.0.0.221) && (ip == 122.167.99.148)

so you want every packet, which has the IP `10.0.0.221` and the IP `122.167.99.148`.